# Check If search query contains something?

Tags: search, noindex

How to check if search query contain some characters? For example I would like to check if search query contain "/".

I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17940444/if-search-query-is-met-function) but it is not working for me. Just to say I am using custom search base.

Example:

site.com/myseachbase/keyword

where "myseachbase" is my custom search base. What I need is way to check if search query has "/", in some cases it is at the end of search query, for example:

site.com/myseachbase/keyword/

How to check for that ending "/" in search URL?

---

**QUESTION UPDATE:**

---

Problem is that I have some custom URLs like:

site.com/myseachbase/keyword

They are practically search results, even visitor open them by clicking on link(s), not by using normal site search.

I need to make them indexable only if:

- there are search results
- it is first search results page, not for any other /page/x
- search query has specific keyword(s)
- search results are correct and usefull results
- plus to add some quality content prepared by editor based on search keyword

After I have done that part, I have nice quality content, custom text based on search query + some images (images are search results) on URLs like:

site.com/myseachbase/keyword

but, if you add "/" at the you will get same page, but another URL, which will met conditions to be indexable too. So, I need way to put "noindex" tag in case if it is that duplicate URL, URL with "/" at the end, because I have no option to create canonicial URL. For that I need something to check for "/".

Comment: I think "/" in a URL is not passed in the query string; I think you need something else. Can you explain why do you need that and what is your purpose?

Comment: @cybmeta I updated my question with detailed explanation, regards.

Comment: See muy answer, what you need is to set the canonical URL in the search results page. You don't need to detect "/" at the end of the URL and you don't need to set "noindex".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the question's update, I think that you need to set the canonical URL:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'cyb_search_results_canonical_URL' );
function cyb_search_results_canonical_URL() {
    if( is_search() ) {
        $link = get_search_link();
        echo '<link rel="canonical" href="' . esc_url( $link ) . '">';
    }
}
```

And your problem with duplicated content is fixed.

Comment: Thank you, that is great, yes I needed `get_search_link();`. Great answer.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to hook onto the search query through `pre_get_posts`. The following snippet will search for `/` in the query.

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','search_query');
function search_query($query){
    if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && is_search()){
        $search = $query->query_vars['s'];
        if (strpos('/', $search) !== false){
            // Found '/' in search query
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working, acctually, it never found "/", even if I type it in search query.

Comment: It might be the query isn't the main query - try removing the `&& $query->is_main_query()` part of the if-statement.

Comment: I rtied to remove all this `if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && is_search()){` and to add `if (strpos('/', $search) !== false){ echo 'Found'; } else { echo 'Not found'; }`, but I always get "Not found", even if I add "/" at the end of search URL. I also tried to change  `strpos('/', $search)` to `strpos('test', $search)`, and to search for "test", but always it is "Not found". Like search query is empty or like it even does not look at search query at all.

Comment: Can you post here what `echo $search;` outputs?

Comment: I tested search output with: `echo 'Search query is: ' .$search. '';`, and output is blank, nothing in my case, even there is search keyword in URL, and there are search results.

Comment: Do you see the `Search query is:`-part though?